# Base class to derive class access - How?

Tags: c++

How is it possible to access derived class's function through base classes object?
I have compiled and run the program without any error (vs2010 express edition).
Can any one give clarification regarding this topic?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    void f1() { cout << " f1 \n"; }
};

class B : public A{
    int x;
public:
    void f2(int x) {this->x = x; cout << "f2 " << this->x <<"\n";}
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    A * aaa = new A();    // created a base instance
    B * b = (B *) aaa;    // typecasted it to derived class
    b->f2(5);   // try to access function, which should not be possible (run-time error?)
    return 0;
}
```

--> output

```
f2 5   // which concept is supports this output?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is a C-style **upcast** which results in **undefined** object content - consider it to be not recommended to be used with C++ because we have much better tools available there. Please take a look into static_cast<> and dynamic_cast<> - they will make sure that your cast will work. As example, if you would have done

```
B * b = dynamic_cast<B*>(aaa);
```

you would not even be able to compile it because A is not polymorphic and even if it would be and the classes do not match, it returns NULL instead of "something undefined".

Please mind that dynamic casts are a bit more expensive than static_cast or C-style casts (which behave more or less like static_casts) - but due to their defined behaviour, you might consider using these at least in debug builds:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    assert(dynamic_cast<B*>(aaa));
#endif
```

This prevents a) upcasts and b) runtime-bugs due to undefined behaviour (I assume that you test using debug builds).

Comment: Thank you Coder02, I know there were various casting keyword for C++ but I never thought that I was performing C-Style Typecasting.

Thank you all for your replies. It has been a great help :)

Comment: Don't get this wrong - a C-style cast is not always bad and does not always result in undefined results in C++ - it's just in your case because A does not inherit from B. @Anders has replied what this looks like in memory and why the result is undefined in this case.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible because there is no such method. You have just invoked **undefined** behavior, and your compiler is playing tricks on you.

Let us play games to witness this [in action](http://ideone.com/3B85u):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  A(int i = 0): value(i) {}

  int value;
};

struct B: A {
  B(int i): A(0), other(i) {}

  void set(int i) { other = i; }

  int other;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  A* a = new A[2];
  B* b = (B*)a;
  b->set(argc);

  std::cout << a->value << " " << (a+1)->value << "\n";
  std::cout << b->value << " " << b->other << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0 1
0 1
```

Oh! How come the second `A` in the array was changed ?

You've lied to the compiler, it lied to you... and the program wrote where it should not have.

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behavior (i.e. it works by accident).

Answer (score 1):

consider this:

```
struct A
{
   int i;
   short s;
};

struct B : A
{
   long p;
};

struct A a;

+-----+-----+
|  i  |  s  |
+-----+-----+

struct B* b = (B*)&a;
```

now access the struct member p;   `(b->p)`

do you think it seems reasonable that p has a valid value? It is still pointing to the 'a' instance.

you should take a look at dynamic_cast and virtual functions

Answer (score 1):

The compile actually treats b->f2 as f2(b)
and f2(b) equals(pseudo code)

```
address_of_x = b+offset_x_in_B
int x;
memcpy(&x, address_of_x, sizeof(int));
std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
```

where offset_x_in_B is the compiler determined value of c++ object model.

So when b is a A instance, the behaviour will be undefined(if A has just an int member, not x, it should be displayed.)